# trying to publish blazor wasm app but mono runtime and class libs out of sync

Tags: asp.net-core, github-pages, blazor, blazor-client-side

#### Describe the bug

I'm trying to publish blazor wasm app to GitHub Pages and aliyun oss using GitHub Actions.
Deploy success,but get error on browser,see [console log](https://gohopo.github.io/).
What I do wrong?

My web.yml

```
name: deploy to web
on:
  push:
    paths: 
    - 'src/Orion.UI.Web/**'
jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: setup dotnet core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@master
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.100

    - name: setup aliyun oss
      uses: manyuanrong/setup-ossutil@master
      with:
        endpoint: oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com
        access-key-id: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        access-key-secret: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET }}

    - name: build
      run: dotnet publish ./src/Orion.UI.Web/Orion.UI.Web.csproj -c Release -o ./bin/publish

    - name: deploy to aliyun oss
      run: ossutil cp -rf ./bin/publish/Orion.UI.Web/dist oss://gohopo-orion/

    - name: deploy to github pages
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@master
      env:
        PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_PAGES_TOKEN }}
        EXTERNAL_REPOSITORY: gohopo/gohopo.github.io
        PUBLISH_BRANCH: master
        PUBLISH_DIR: ./bin/publish/Orion.UI.Web/dist
```

action result:
[image url](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8192266/71986387-607c4a80-3267-11ea-94b4-bf98918cf349.jpg)

error on browser:
[image url](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8192266/71986481-86095400-3267-11ea-8dbf-152ad25ba7dd.jpg)

#### To Reproduce

My .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.1.0-preview4.19579.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

#### Further technical details

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor 3.1.0-preview4.19579.2
- dotnet-version: 3.1.100
- github actions build

Comment: check your `<base href`

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry,I didn't make it clear,i edited it. You can see the console log [link](https://gohopo.github.io/). And what can i do for 'mono runtime and class libs out of sync' error?

Comment: @aguafrommars sorry,I didn't use 'a' or 'base' tag.You can see the console log [link](https://gohopo.github.io/)

Comment: and this is your issue, you should point your base href to the script location

Answer (score 0):

Your site looks good now but there are some mistakes and updates about GitHub Actions workflow, I leave an example workflow.

Here is a workflow for Hugo.

For more options and usages, see the latest README: [peaceiris/actions-gh-pages: GitHub Actions for GitHub Pages](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages)

- Set `on.push.branches` to trigger a workflow with a specific branch like `main` or `master`.
- Set a specific tag of action instead of `@master`.

```yaml
name: github pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Set a branch name to trigger deployment

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - run: build-someting

      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./public
          publish_branch: your-branch  # default: gh-pages
```